# Show error in the case. C++

Tags: c++, validation, input, output, return-value

How can I show an error to the client of my code in the case?

Here is the function which will be used by someone:

```
double firstTaskSum(int n, double x)
{
    if(n < 0)
    {
        cout << ("n is invalid! n : " + std::to_string(n) + ". And must be n >= 0.");
        return;
    }

    if(x == 0)
    {
        cout << ("x is invalid! 0 to power of 0 is undefined.");
        return;
    }

    return firstTaskSumUp(0, n, x, 1, 1);
}
```

It gives an error when I try to compile it because it returns nothing. How can I go around it? I would not like to return bogus variables since they may be an actual output for some input.

When using such code:

```
double firstTaskSum(int n, double x)
{
    if(n < 0)
    {throw invalid_argument("n is invalid! n : " + std::to_string(n) + ". And must be n >= 0.");}

    if(x == 0)
    {throw invalid_argument("x is invalid! 0 to power of 0 is undefined.");}

    return firstTaskSumUp(0, n, x, 1, 1);
}
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

And I would like the error to be nicely output to the console and flow of the program not to stop.

Comment: Throw an exception and handle it in the upper level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw an exception:

```
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

double firstTaskSum(int n, double x)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("n must be positive");
    }

    if (x == 0)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("x can't be 0");
    }

    return firstTaskSumUp(0, n, x, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: How would I go around catching the `invalid_argument` exception? For example, I know that I can catch a plain text using `catch(const char* msg)`.

Comment: @ЯрикТроф `catch`'s parameter is the type: `catch(const invalid_argument& e)`.

Comment: And how can I output the message which was passed as a parameter to `invalid_argument` ?

Comment: @ЯрикТроф You can call the [`what()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) method on the exception you caught, it will return the message you constructed the exception with.

Answer (score 0):

Another option beside throwing exceptions is to have a function check for argument validity.

```
if (IsArgumentValid(1, 1))
    firstTaskSum(1, 1);
else
    cout << "Invalid arguments\n";
```